# Crash when use swift WKWebView didFailNavigation to Objective-C file

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

so I have an SDK written in swift that overrides WKWebView delegation to check SSL certificates/security measure.

[image: Swift]

and I want to use it on my Objective-C project :

[image: Objective C]

The delegation works as intended, but when try to execute didFailNavigation, it crashes... but when I try to use it on a swift project, it works perfectly. do you guys know why this happening in objective-c?

And one more question, in swift I can do the like this

```
self.webView?.navigationDelegate = safeWebDelegate.wkWebDelegate as? WKNavigationDelegate
```

but in iOS I cannot do :

```
self.webView.navigationDelegate = (WKNavigationDelegate *)safeWebDelegate.wkWebDelegate;
```

it says that WKNavigationDelegate not found. Is there any workaround on this?  Thanks

Comment: Fix all of the warnings and maybe the crashes will stop.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, the crashes fixed now. just one more thing how i can do this in obj-c self.webView?.navigationDelegate = safeWebDelegate.wkWebDelegate as? WKNavigationDelegate ?